# Python How do you change a specific value on a specific line of a file?

Tags: python

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
```

this is the line in an existing file and all i want to change is the value of 0 to the value of 1 now I'm just wondering how would i do that in python?
I've seen other people posting on importing `subprocess` and using `subprocess.call([])` but that is a little unclear to me so I just need someone to simplify that for me and maybe explain a line of code I could use to alter a certain line of code and change that value of 0 to 1 and explain in detail on how to do so, thank you very much your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the line number of the code ? or Is it a specific pattern that you want to find & replace ?

Comment: i just checked and it is line 100

Comment: and i want to keep the same pattern of the code i just need to change that 0 into the value of 1, thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Actuall, there is no need to do it in python. It can be achieved using `sed` as follows:

```
sed -i 's/\(if \[ "`id -u`" -eq \)0/\11/' myfile
```

This one-liner is basically looking for the specific pattern in your file, and replace 0 by 1 where this pattern is found.

If you want to replace the pattern only on line number 100:

```
sed -i '100s/\(if \[ "`id -u`" -eq \)0/\11/' myfile
```

Let me know if you have a specific requirement to do it in python. I can add the similar code for python as well. That code will also follow the similar approach based on regular expressions.